# Filter dmidecode memory controller for supported speeds

Tags: linux, command-line, filter, dmidecode

as a newbie to linux kernel and all the commands, I am reaching out to you guys, hoping you can help me solve my issue.

When running the next command

`sudo dmidecode -t 5`

I get the following output:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.4 present.

Handle 0x0084, DMI type 5, 46 bytes
Memory Controller Information
        Error Detecting Method: None
        Error Correcting Capabilities:
                None
        Supported Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Current Interleave: One-way Interleave
        Maximum Memory Module Size: 32768 MB
        Maximum Total Memory Size: 491520 MB
        Supported Speeds:
                70 ns
                60 ns
        Supported Memory Types:
                FPM
                EDO
                DIMM
                SDRAM
        Memory Module Voltage: 3.3 V
        Associated Memory Slots: 15
                0x0085
                0x0086
                0x0087
                0x0088
                0x0089
                0x008A
                0x008B
                0x008C
                0x008D
                0x008E
                0x008F
                0x0090
                0x0091
                0x0092
                0x0093
        Enabled Error Correcting Capabilities:
                None
```

Is there any command to filter the output so I get the supported speeds (70ns, 60ns) in any way?

I tried

```
sudo dmidecode -t 5 | grep -i -e DMI -e speed
```

which gave me this output:

```
# dmidecode 3.0
Handle 0x0084, DMI type 5, 46 bytes
        Supported Speeds:
```

but this doesn't output the following lines.

Any suggestions are very welcome, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list the supported speeds:

```
dmidecode | awk '/^\t[^\t]/ { speeds = 0 }; /^\tSupported Speeds:/ { speeds = 1 } /^\t\t/ && speeds'
```

This works by matching lines as follows:

- lines starting with a single tab mean that we’re not expecting speeds;
- lines starting with a single tab followed by “Supported Speeds:” mean that we *are* expecting speeds;
- lines starting with two tabs when we are expecting speeds are output as-is.

Comment: This solution works like a charm! I like the way you explained it step by step